# How to disable Spacemacs logo from splash screen?

Tags: spacemacs

I want to remove the image because it unnecessarily takes space. I've tried `fancy-splash-image nil` but it didn't work.

What should I place in my .spacemacs (or wherever) and in which part.

Answer (score 5):

There's a variable called `dotspacemacs-startup-banner` that you can set at your initialisation file in order to remove the banner.

Your initialisation file is either `~/.spacemacs` or `~/.spacemacs.d/init.el`. There you'll find a function called `dotspacemacs/init` which contains a list of variables and their values (with an explanation what each of them do), you just need to find `dotspacemacs-startup-banner` and replace its value to `nil`.

Here is the full documentation of the variable for the sake of completeness

> dotspacemacs-startup-banner is a variable defined in
>   ‘core-dotspacemacs.el’. Its value is ‘official’
>
> Documentation: 
>   Specify the startup banner. Default value is
>   ‘official’, it displays the official spacemacs logo. An integer value
>   is the index of text banner, ‘random’ chooses a random text banner in
>   ‘core/banners’ directory. A string value must be a path to a .PNG
>   file. If the value is nil then no banner is displayed.